# How to setup the actions with considering database design of rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

Assume you have the model called 'Topic' as a parent, and 'Comment' as a child.
On the url 'topics/show/35' you can see all the comments that belongs to this topic ID#35.

When logged-in user want to post his new comment at this page,
should I write 'comment_create' action in topics_controller.rb?
or just write 'create' action in comments_controller.rb, and call it from this page?
Which one is regular way??

If I call 'create' action in comments_controller, how can I write in view to pass

1. 'Model name' to add comments into
2. 'Models ID#'
3. 'comment body'

or should I just write actions separately like this?

controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
  def create_in_topic
   code here! to add new comment record that belongs to topic....
  end


  def create_in_user
   code here! to add new comment record that belongs to user....
  end
```

for your information, comment adding action should be something like this.

```
  def create

   @topic = Topic.find(params[:topics][:id] )
   @user_who_commented = current_user 
   @comment = Comment.build_from( @topic, @user_who_commented.id, params[:topics][:body] )
   @comment.save
   redirect_to :back   
   flash[:notice] = "comment added!"

  end
```

**Example** Updated!!!

views/topics/show.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Posted by</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>

<% @topic.comment_threads.each do |comment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment.id %></td>
    <td><%= comment.title %></td>
    <td><%= comment.body %></td>
    <td><%= comment.subject %></td>
    <td><%= comment.user.user_profile.nickname if comment.user.user_profile %></td>
    <td> **Comment destroy method needed here!!!** </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<%=form_for :topics, url: url_for( :controller => :topics, :action => :add_comment ) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :'comment' %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
    </div> 

    <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => @topic.id %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

controllers/topics_controller.rb

```
  def add_comment
   @topic = Topic.find(params[:topics][:id] )
   @user_who_commented = current_user
   @comment = Comment.build_from( @topic, @user_who_commented.id, params[:topics][:body] )
   @comment.save
   redirect_to :back
   flash[:notice] = "comment added!"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straight forward implementation it's going to be an action (ie: add_comment) in your Topic Controller. Once the view call the TopicController#add_comment action you will have all your Topic information and also the comment data so you can easily add the comment to the Topic from there.

Let me know if you need further help. 
FedeX

Comment: Thanks!!! What if you delete your posted comment one by one, from the page /topics/show/35. I mean just like here on this stackoverflow's comments. Do you put 'comment_destroy method' in topics_controller.rb? or do you need to call 'destroy method' and pass parameters to comments_controller? which way is usual?

Comment: No worries, the easiest way it's just use your already existing _destroy method, lets say in the view when you are displaying the associated comments and you want to allow the user to delete them you could simply add something like this:

    <% unless comment.new_record? %>

        <div>

            <%= comment_form.label :_destroy, 'Remove comment?' %>

            <%= comment_form.check_box :_destroy %>

        </div>

    <% end %>

Comment: Thanks! I just added my codes to my question. Please take a look at example part. How do you modify this to implement both multiple-records deleting method by checkbox, and adding comments method??

Comment: Wait there is something wrong in your view, why do you have that @ all_comments ? You should be getting the topic's comments from the @ topic instead ( like @ topic.comments )

Comment: Check my answer in this other question, it's the same for you but change Incident Class by Topic and Person by Comment and that's exactly what you need! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11423342/1505580)

Comment: @ FedeX I changed @ all_comments to @ topic.comment_threads . Please take a look at view. I'm using acts_as_commentable_with_thread gem that's why it's not @ topic.comment . In this case, how can I implement both multiple-records deleting method by checkbox, and adding comments method?? can you show me example?

Comment: You didn't mention you are using act_as_commentable gem. In that case, I'm sorry but I'm not sure because I never used that gem but I think in that case you should use the comment_controller instead. If you don't really need that gem you could achieve what you want easily with nested forms (it's default in rails!). [like I show here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11423342/1505580)

Comment: Sorry about that. but it's almost the same as you code directly instead of using this gem. What if you just do it in normal way, how do you code multiple-records deleting method in controller? All I need to know it that for now:)

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not to sure because that gem, but you could try something like this:

```
<%=form_for @topic, url: url_for( :controller => :topics, :action => :add_comment ) do |f| %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Posted by</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

    <% @topic.comment_threads.each do |comment| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :comment_threads, comment do |comment_form| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= comment.id %></td>
                <td><%= comment.title %></td>
                <td><%= comment.body %></td>
                <td><%= comment.subject %></td>
                <td><%= comment.user.user_profile.nickname if comment.user.user_profile %></td>
                <td>Delete? <%= comment_form.check_box :_destroy %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </table>


    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :'comment' %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :body %>
    </div> 

    <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => @topic.id %>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if it helps you! FedeX